# Best and fastest way to use constants

Tags: python, optimization, constants

Here are the files I have for the moment:

```
main.py
functions.py
constants.py
```

I am working on a project in python which requires some constants and I decided to stock them in a python file called `constants.py` which looks like:

```
A = 5
B = 6
C = 7
# etc.
```

This file is both imported as a module in `functions.py` and `main.py`
However I would like to add some scripting and change these constants in `main.py` with parameters for examples, but if I change these constant in `main.py` they don't change anyway in `functions.py` which uses it a lot
And I didn't find any solution to that problem yet, so I am using a dictionary but dictionary takes 3 times longer to access a variable i.e:

```
timeit.timeit(stmt='b = a[5]; b = 0', setup="a = {5:5}", number=5000)
# 0.000302988540795468
timeit.timeit(stmt='b = a; b = 0', setup="a = 5", number=5000)
# 0.00013507954133143288
```

Comment: If they're a-changin' they ain't **constants**…

Comment: If you want to change them, they aren't really constants! Why not make them *parameters* when calling the functions from `functions.py`?

Comment: If you have reached the point where variables lookups are a performance issue it's time to stop using python and move to a lower-level language (or write a Cython extensions). Micro-optimizations ain't gonna save you.

Comment: More likely variable lookups aren't a performance issue and you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I know it's weird that constants change, but that is how they are called here to generate a snowflake, and appart from the beginning they should not change.
I'm not using parameters because I have around 15 _constants_, it would be long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the fact that these are not constants, you are probably changing the wrong thing when you're trying to change the values accross files. Use `import constants` and always refer to `constants.A` and changes to `constants.A` will be reflected everywhere. Do not do `from constants import A` and do not do `A = constants.A; A = 10` and expect that to change `A` to 10 everywhere. Rather do `constants.A = 10`.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I was looking for, it was stupid but I couldn't find it